# Separate Javascript file not Functioning

Tags: javascript

Good day, I just made a simple javascript file. my only issue is the alert is not popping up. any ideas? any comment is appreciated thank you.

html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="practice2.js"></script>
        <title>Practice</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>sample paragraph</p>

        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>


    </body>
</html>
```

javascipt file:

```
var year = 2018;

function myFunction() {
    if ( year == 2018 ) 
        {   
        alert("it is equal to 2018");
        }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just define your function needs to call your function like following:

```js
var year = 2018;

function myFunction() {
    if ( year == 2018 ) {   
        alert("it is equal to 2018");
    }
}

myFunction();// call your function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-You missed to call the function

```js
var year = 2018;

function myFunction() {
    if ( year == 2018 ) 
        {   
        alert("it is equal to 2018");
        }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="practice2.js"></script>
        <title>Practice</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>sample paragraph</p>

        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>

        <input type="submit"  value="Call Function" onclick="myFunction()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```